# Django Page Not found error : Sudden in process of learning

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, web-frameworks

I was in motion of learning Django, suddenly encountered Page not found Error in all pages.
This is my URL pattern file code:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^analysis/', include('analysis.urls')),
    url(r'^music/', include('music.urls')),
]
```

but while accessing any of the pages page not found error is coming:
I have run the server on port 8084,

```
python .\manage.py runserver 8084
```

Accessing urls:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8084/admin
http://127.0.0.1:8084/music
http://127.0.0.1:8084/analysis
```

All of the views are available and pages were previously displayed but now it is not working. I have tried re-starting the server also but no help.

Kindly suggest me what could be the possibility of error.

Comment: Note that the URLs should be `http://127.0.0.1:8084/admin/`, `http://127.0.0.1:8084/music/` and `http://127.0.0.1:8084/analysis/` with trailing slashes. Do they work?

Comment: Same is happening with another project also, is their a possibility if it is a django module error?

Comment: You haven't said whether the URLs with the slashes work. I'm not sure what you mean by a "django module error" - it's very unlikely that you are hitting a bug in Django.

Comment: Most important thing is, what did you do when this "suddenly" happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the runserver like this:

```
python manage.py runserver 8084
```

Comment: I am not quiet sure why but this worked.
Can you please explain the difference between:
python manage.py runserver 8084
python .\manage.py runserver 8084

because i don't feel any?